# Is Iblis still alive?

Tags: shaitan

Jinns can live only for a certain time : a few hundred or a few thousand years. However Iblis was there when Adam alaihissalaam was created and that means he must have been born before that. Tens of thousands of years have passed since then ?

How can Iblis still be alive ? Is it because Allah gave him respite till the day of judgement ?

Please answer

Jazakallhahu Khair g

Answer (score 0):

In the quran, Allah (SAW) said in surah Sad I believe, that he has granted Iblis the special ability to live until the end of times

38:79
قَالَ رَبِّ فَأَنظِرْنِىٓ إِلَىٰ يَوْمِ يُبْعَثُونَ
He said, "My Lord, then reprieve me until the Day they are resurrected."
— Saheeh International
38:80
قَالَ فَإِنَّكَ مِنَ ٱلْمُنظَرِينَ
[Allah] said, "So indeed, you are of those reprieved
— Saheeh International
Surah sad 79-80

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Iblis is still alive today.  He was to be cast into hellfire, but, he requested and received a reprieve until the Day of Resurrection.  He promised to deceive any he could until then, but, the Qur'an also says that on that day, he will disavow anyone who listened to him.